# problems with lisp and do construct with itterating

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Firstly, I am having this problem. The code I generated isn't iterating thru each word, but instead thru the entire passed argument. I am using a do loop to pass information into a hash table.

```
(defun set_isa (partOfSpeech &rest words)

(do ((wordVar words))
((null wordVar) nil) 

(putp partOfSpeech word-dict wordVar)
(setf wordVar (cdr wordVar))))
```

With this I am getting this as a result using trace

```
(set_isa 'Verb 'Talk 'Run 'jump )

1. Trace: (SET_ISA 'VERB 'TALK 'RUN 'JUMP)
1. Trace: SET_ISA ==> NIL
NIL
```

And when I call the hashtable, it only adds the last passed argument

```
#S(HASH-TABLE :TEST FASTHASH-EQL (VERB . (JUMP)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the way to understand what is going on here is to annotate your code so it *tells you what it's doing*.  This may seem an antique way of debugging, but in a dynamic, conversational language like CL it's a really good approach.  Here is a version of your function using more conventional names for things, and also using conventional indetnation, together with stubs for your missing code to make it all runnable.

```
(defvar *word-dict* nil)

(defun set-isa (part-of-speech &rest words)
  (do ((wtail words))
      ((null wtail) nil) 
    (putp part-of-speech *word-dict* wtail)
    (setf wtail (cdr wtail))))

(defun putp (part-of-speech dict thing)
  (format *debug-io* "~&putp: ~A ~A ~A~%" part-of-speech dict thing))
```

So this is now runnable, and `putp` will print what it gets as arguments.

```
 > (set-isa 'verb 'talk 'run 'jump )
putp: verb nil (talk run jump)
putp: verb nil (run jump)
putp: verb nil (jump)
nil
```

So even without having the code which is actually buggy here, which is almost certainly `putp`, you can work out what the problem is:  `putp` *replaces* whatever value is stored in the hash table with its argument.  So the only value that ends up in the table is the last one.  So we need to fix that, which I'll do later.

But in fact that's not the only problem.

First of all you're using `do` in a very odd way. The syntax of `do` explicitly allows initialisation *and stepping* forms, so you should actually use the stepping form rather than doing it in the body.

```
(defun set-isa (part-of-speech &rest words)
  (do ((wtail words (rest wtail)))
      ((null wtail) nil) 
    (putp part-of-speech *word-dict* wtail)))
```

Secondly you're calling `putp` on *all the tails of your list*: you probably want to be calling it on just the individual words.  You could do this by simply passing it the car of each tail, but as Martin Buchmann points out in the other answer you might instead look for a construct in the language which iterates over the elements of a list.  And there are plenty of these, and `dolist` is one of them:

```
(defun set-isa (part-of-speech &rest words)
  (dolist (word words)
    (putp part-of-speech *word-dict* word)))
```

And now

```
(set-isa 'verb 'talk 'run 'jump )
putp: verb nil talk
putp: verb nil run
putp: verb nil jump
nil
```

Note the way `putp` is called is not compatible with the previous version: it's now called on the words, not the tails of the list.

So finally, let's write a version of `putp` that works.  I'll first write a very naive version:

```
(defvar *word-dict* (make-hash-table))

(defun putp (part-of-speech dict thing)
  (let ((entries (gethash part-of-speech dict '())))
    (setf (gethash part-of-speech dict) (cons thing entries))))
```

And this works, but not in a very good way:

```
> (gethash 'verb *word-dict* '())
nil
nil

> (set-isa 'verb 'talk 'run 'jump )
nil

> (gethash 'verb *word-dict* '())
(jump run talk)
t

> (set-isa 'verb 'talk 'run 'jump )
nil

> (gethash 'verb *word-dict* '())
(jump run talk jump run talk)
t
```

So that's OK, so long as you only run it once.  Well, we can do better than this:

- we can use a more idiomatic way of pushing new things onto the list stored in the hashtable;
- we can avoid the duplicate entry thing while also being more idiomatic.

Like this:

```
(defun putp (part-of-speech dict thing)
  (pushnew thing (gethash part-of-speech dict)))
```

So, now:

```
 > (gethash 'verb *word-dict* '())
nil
nil

> (set-isa 'verb 'talk 'run 'jump )
nil

> (gethash 'verb *word-dict* '())
(jump run talk)
t

> (set-isa 'verb 'talk 'run 'jump )
nil

> (gethash 'verb *word-dict* '())
(jump run talk)
```

This is much better.  You can look up `push`, and `pushnew` to see what they do.

Comment: Just a sliver of code; easy to fall through the cracks! I might be tempted to call the new function `push-isa` instead of `set-isa`.

Comment: @exnihilo: I'd probably call it `ensure-isa`, based on the various MOP functions like `ensure-generic-function`, since it ensures that its arguments have the right POS tags.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to SO. I see a few issues with our question and hope I can give you some hints.

### Indentation

Please indent your code properly. This will lead to more readable code and will increase the probability that others can help you.

```
(defun set_isa (partOfSpeech &rest words)
  "Put an understandable docstring here!"
  (do ((wordVar words))
      ((null wordVar) nil) 
    (putp partOfSpeech word-dict wordVar)
    (setf wordVar (cdr wordVar))))
```

You will find more advice on style [here](https://lisp-lang.org/style-guide/). See also the [Info tab](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/common-lisp/info) for a collection of references.

### Runable examples

In our function `putp` isn't defined. So I cannot run your code and see what error to get exactly, etc. Please give always complete examples and a clear description of what you expect and what you get. The part with the `hash-table` isn't clear at all. Where does it come from? How is it used in our code?

### do loops

Check a beginner reference for the correct syntax of `do` and its relatives. If you want to iterate through a list using `do` try `dolist`.

```
(dolist (item '(a b c d))
  (print item))
```

Using `do` you could achieve the same with this construct:

```
(do ((items '(a b c d) (rest items)))
    ((null items))
  (print (first items)))
```

I might seem tricky to get the parenthesis right in the first place but if you've got the logic behind it right it will become easier. You don't need the `setf` part as `do` will take care of it.