# Reset each value in hashtable to nil in Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

This function resets the value for each of the specified parts of speech to NIL using putp.
The first argument is a hashtable, for this example, lets call it word-dict.
There are a variable number of parts of speech passed to resetPartsOfSpeech.

Example:
(resetPartsOfSpeech word-dict 'subject 'verb 'prep 'directObj)

```
(defun resetPartsOfSpeech(word-dict &rest parts)
(do ((partsVar parts (cdr partsVar)))
( (null partsVar) T)
;;; procces the car 
(putp NIL word-dict (car partsVar))
))

; here is the results of the function
#S(HASH-TABLE :TEST FASTHASH-EQL (NIL . VERB) (LICKED . VERB) (HAS . VERB) (ATE . VERB) (RAN . VERB) (TAUGHT . VERB)
```

As you see, it only adds the NIL variable to the list, not clearing them all out.

Helper Functions I Have, The job of these two functions is to put and get data from the hashtable created.

```
; creating the hash table
(setf word-dict (MAKE-HASH-TABLE))

(defun putp (symbol ht value)
(if (ATOM symbol)
    (setf (gethash symbol ht) value)
    (ERROR "~s is not a valid symbol for putp" symbol)
))

(defun getp (symbol ht)
 (gethash symbol ht) )

(defun isa(word partOfSpeech)      ; this function returns T if the specified word is that specified partOfSpeech,  
; otherwise, NIL is returned. 
(eql (getp word word-dict) partOfSpeech))

(defun set_isa (partOfSpeech &rest words)    ; this function defines each
word in the list of words to the specified partOfSpeech
```

; in the dictionary (hard code word-dict). 
    (do ((wordVar words (cdr wordVar)) )
        ( (NULL wordVar ) T)
        ;;; proccess the CAR
        (putp (car wordVar) word-dict partOfSpeech)
        (print (car wordVar))))

What I am having trouble understanding is that how I should go about itterating thru each value in the hash table. What I was considering was doing a nested do or dolist loop but can't quite figure out how to go about that with the values from the table, or if that is even possible.

Comment: It would help, if you post your code formatted and indented. That would improve readability. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fundamental problem is with:

```
(putp NIL word-dict (car partsVar))
```

When `putp` is called, `nil` is bound to `symbol`, `word-dict` is bound to `ht`, and `(car partsVar)`, i.e. the next symbol in the list of parts of speech, is bound to `value`. Within `putp` the expression:

```
(setf (gethash symbol ht) value)
```

becomes:

```
(setf (gethash 'nil word-dict) (car partsVar))
```

Here, `(gethash 'nil word-dict)` is the *place* that is set to the value `(car partsVar)`. Since there is no `'nil` key in the hash table yet, a new key is created and given the value `(car partsVar)`, which is `'verb` in the OP example.

In the original `putp` expression, `(car partsVal)` should have been in the `symbol` position as that is the key which should be updated:

```
(defun resetPartsOfSpeech (word-dict &rest parts)
  (do ((partsVar parts (cdr partsVar)))
      ((null partsVar) t)
    (putp (car partsVar) word-dict 'nil)))
```

Although this solves the problem, there is a better solution.

```
(defun reset-parts-of-speech (word-dict &rest parts)
  (dolist (part parts)
    (putp part word-dict 'nil)))
```

When you want to do a simple iteration over a list of elements, symbols for parts of speech in this case, just use a simple `dolist`. Additionally, it would be good to get into better habits with respect to Lisp style. Prefer kebab-case to camel-case; put all closing parentheses on one line (almost always); use proper indentation to make program structure clear. A good lisp-aware text editor can be most helpful for the last two.

Here is some testing in the REPL using a `set-isa` function based on [the previous question by OP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61300570/6879826):

```
SCRATCH> (defvar *word-dict* (make-hash-table))
*WORD-DICT*
SCRATCH> (set-isa 'verb 'eat 'sleep 'walk)
NIL
SCRATCH> (set-isa 'noun 'cake 'ice-cream 'pizza)
NIL
SCRATCH> (gethash 'verb *word-dict*)
(WALK SLEEP EAT)
T
SCRATCH> (gethash 'noun *word-dict*)
(PIZZA ICE-CREAM CAKE)
T
SCRATCH> (set-isa 'adjective 'delicious 'sweet 'crispy)
NIL
SCRATCH> (gethash 'adjective *word-dict*)
(CRISPY SWEET DELICIOUS)
T
SCRATCH> (resetPartsOfSpeech *word-dict* 'verb)
T
SCRATCH> (gethash 'verb *word-dict*)
NIL
T
SCRATCH> (gethash 'noun *word-dict*)
(PIZZA ICE-CREAM CAKE)
T
SCRATCH> (reset-parts-of-speech *word-dict* 'adjective 'noun)
NIL
SCRATCH> (gethash 'noun *word-dict*)
NIL
T
SCRATCH> (gethash 'adjective *word-dict*)
NIL
T
```

---

### Update

The above was predicated on OP statement: "*This function resets the value for each of the specified parts of speech to NIL...,*" which seemed to suggest that OP wants the hash table to store parts of speech as keys and lists of words as the associated values. This also seems to align with a [previous question posted by OP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61300570/6879826). But, after an exchange of comments, it seems that OP may prefer a hash table with individual words as keys and parts of speech as the associated values. It is unclear how words which may be associated with multiple parts of speech should be handled.

The hash table shown in OP example code `#S(HASH-TABLE :TEST FASTHASH-EQL (NIL . VERB) (LICKED . VERB) ;...,` along with OP comments, supports this second interpretation. If this is the case, then what does it mean to "reset each value" in the hash table to `'nil`? Perhaps the sensible thing to do is to remove each entry entirely which has a value that matches a provided part-of-speech argument.

This can easily be accomplished by using `dolist` to loop over the list of parts of speech, and subsequently mapping over the hash table with `maphash` and a function that removes any entry holding a matching value:

```
(defun remove-parts-of-speech (word-dict &rest parts)
  (dolist (part parts)
    (maphash #'(lambda (k v) (if (eql v part) (remhash k word-dict)))
             word-dict)))
```

Here is another REPL demonstration using OP's current `set-isa` function which populates a hash table with words for keys and parts of speech for values. After populating the hash table with nine words which are `'noun`s, `'verb`s, and `'adjectives`, the `remove-parts-of-speech` function is used to remove all entries which are nouns or verbs from `*word-dict*`. After this, only the three adjective entries remain in the hash table.

```
CL-USER> (defvar *word-dict* (make-hash-table))
*WORD-DICT*
CL-USER> (set-isa 'verb 'run 'jump 'climb)

RUN 
JUMP 
CLIMB 
T
CL-USER> (set-isa 'noun 'hat 'shoe 'scarf)

HAT 
SHOE 
SCARF 
T
CL-USER> (set-isa 'adjective 'salty 'spicy 'sour)

SALTY 
SPICY 
SOUR 
T
CL-USER> *word-dict*
#<HASH-TABLE :TEST EQL :COUNT 9 {1003CE10C3}>
CL-USER> (hash-table-count *word-dict*)
9
CL-USER> (remove-parts-of-speech *word-dict* 'noun 'verb)
NIL
CL-USER> (hash-table-count *word-dict*)
3
CL-USER> (gethash 'spicy *word-dict*)
ADJECTIVE
T
```

Comment: Well, in either of your updated functions, they aren't resetting the hash table or the verb in question? not sure what you mean

Comment: @RoleChapa -- I just noticed that your `putp` function seems quite different from the one in your earlier question. The accepted answer there creates a hash table where parts of speech are keys (and this is how my answer works); but it looks like your hash table in this question is using words as keys, and parts of speech as values. Which is correct? You need to add enough code to create a [mcve] here so that we can see how your hash table is created.

Comment: Ok so what should I add? In the earlier question, my putp statement is just a function call, and in this question I have the function declaration and the call to it. So in both instances it's the same function. Again, not sure what you want me to add? I have there how I create the hash table also. What did you do to the putp statement?

Comment: @RoleChapa -- this question states: "_This function resets the value for each of the specified parts of speech...._" This seems to indicate that the part of speech is the _key_, and the word is the _value_. Is this correct? That is not what the sample hash table seems to show. I see the `putp` definition, but it behaves differently than `putp` in the earlier answer. Show code that actually creates the hash table so that we can copy-paste and evaluate; and clarify: what is the key and what is the value?

Comment: Well, what I want to do is reset it, empty it I suppose. If verb had some values, run reset function and it has nothing but nil. Let me post the updated set-isa function I finished and got working.

Comment: This is the unclear part: you want to reset "_the value for each of the specified parts of speech to NIL_." This sounds like you want to go from a hash table containing `('verb . '(run walk stand))` to one containing `('verb . '())`. This also seems to be in line with your previous question. But the hash table shown has `('run . 'verb)`. What does it mean to reset this specified part of speech to NIL? `('nil . 'verb)`? Setting keys to `'nil` doesn't make sense. `('run . 'nil)`? This doesn't make sense either.

Comment: Look at my sample interaction; it seems to do what you have described in your last comment. If I am missing something, help me understand.

Comment: well, it might be a combo of me not fully understanding lisp so well, and my weak skills

But when i run getHash, yes it does show the results You get
NIL ;
T

But when i (print word-dict) It still shows all of the words I added using set-isa but at the end it shows the NIL verb

#S(HASH-TABLE :TEST FASTHASH-EQL (LICKED . VERB) (HAS . VERB) (ATE . VERB) (RAN . VERB) (TAUGHT . VERB) (THREW . VERB)
   (SAT . VERB) (PET . VERB) (VERB . NIL))

Comment: I want to reset it, clear the verb's words in the hash table.

This function resets the value for each of the specified parts of speech to NIL using putp.  The first argument is a word-dict.  There are a variable number of parts of speech passed to resetPartsOfSpeech

(resetPartsOfSpeech word-dict partOfSpeech1 partOfSpeech2 ...)

Comment: The problem is in the hash table. I don't think that `'(licked . verb)` is what you want, and it is not what the accepted solution for `set-isa` provided. What in my interaction looks wrong? In particular, note that in my example I have `'('verb . '(eat sleep walk))`, which is what I think you want from your description (just not from the hash table literal that you have shown). After the reset, my example shows `'(verb . '())`; is this not correct?

Comment: I added a few more functions that i am using and have created, so you may get a better idea of what I am trying to do. notably , the set_isa function i finished, and the isa function i also finished earlier today.

Comment: but actually, yes, the way I have it formatted is how I would want for it to be printed, it isolates each word to its own list and i am able to easily compare with isa since it is like that.

Comment: "_it isolates each word to its own list_" is what does not make sense. See my earlier comment: what does it mean to reset that? `'(eat . verb)` --> `'(nil . verb)`? What does it mean to have a `'nil` key? Or, `'(eat . verb)` --> `'(eat . nil)`? What does it mean to have a word without a part of speech in `*word-dict*`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212055/discussion-between-role-chapa-and-ex-nihilo).